# Как настроить очистку и ограничение кеша

Tags: битрикс, кэширование

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить проблему с большим кешем.
Периодически срабатывает автоочистка (управляемый кеш). Но не понятно, в какое время и с какой периодичностью он очищается.
Приходится чистить в ручную часто.
И при очистке видно, что он занимает более 40 ГБ!!!.

Можно ли как то настроить периодичность автоматической очистки, а еще лучше, автоочистка, когда кеш начинает превышать определенный размер.

При ручной очистке видно, что много чистит в каталоге /bitrix/html_pages/

Comment: Решение про удаление кеша с помощью скрипта в кроне это не решение, это скорее временная мера. Вам нужно пройтись по страницам и посмотреть, почему у вас большой кеш: либо это так и должно быть, либо слишком больше время кеширования, либо создание кеша настроено не правильно и используется на страницах/в компонентах не правильно... К примеру, если стоит галочка "учитывать права доступа", для какой-нибудь страницы новостей "для всех" - то создаются сотни файлов одной и той же новости под разные настройки групп пользователей...

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать настроить CRON (по часам/дням/месяцам) в панели вашего хостинга.
Для этого нужно написать простой php скрипт, который будет удалять содержимое определенно каталога. Далее, залить этот скрипт на хостинг и в настройках CRON указать путь к нему и как часто вызывать этот скрипт.

Пример скрипта для этого:

```
$files = glob('path/to/temp/*'); // get all file names

foreach($files as $file) { // iterate files

  if(is_file($file)) {
    unlink($file); // delete file
  }

}
```

Comment: ПРо крон находил способ, спасибо.
Но вот cron не настроен, без него может есть какой то способ?

Comment: ну я вижу только вариант с cron - он есть на 95% хостингов или если у вас vds/vps то его так же не сложно настроить по мануалам.

Comment: Ну да, вообще CRON есть, установлен ISP Менеджер, правильно ли я понимаю, что нужно указать полный путь к файлу со скриптом в качестве команды и настроить периодичность (в скрипте, так же указывать ПОЛНЫЙ путь к сайту?)

Comment: Да, все верно. Попробуйте, должен вам подойти так подход